# kong.conf.default is read only in Docker through Linux Containers

Tags: docker, kong, kong-plugin

After Kong has been installed in windows using docker (Linux containers), I need to update kong.conf.default or kong.conf file for few extra plugins.

[image]

When I am trying to update the kong.conf.default using the following command, it says me Read Only.

```
vi kong.conf.default
```

As well it is not providing me to chmod by following command and it throws error "*chmod: kong.conf.default: Operation not permitted*".

```
chmod 777 kong.conf.default
```

Please need your support. Advance thanks.

Comment: Did you bind mount those files from your host ? If yes did you check that the container user has write permission on those files ? Side note: [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) specifically points out that pasting code/commands/error messages in images is a bad practice. Thanks.

Comment: Which docker image you are using?

Answer (score 2):

copy the kong.conf.default outside the container, rename it to kong.conf, change it like you need it and mount it inside the container.

Look here my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  kong:
    container_name: kong
    image: kong:2.1.3-centos
    environment:
      ...
    volumes:
      - ./kong.yml:/usr/local/kong/declarative/kong.yml
      - ./kong.conf:/etc/kong/kong.conf
    ports:
      ....
```